# unable to get php server response into html5 OpenFL haxe app

Tags: php, html, haxe, openfl

I have a json string being printed using `Lib.print(string);` in haxe/php and am hosting that on my localhost

I've checked http://localhost/index.php, and it does indeed print the json object as text.

My HTML5 app has the following code in it

```
var h = new HttpJs('http://localhost/index.php');

function traceFunc (d:String){trace(d); }
h.onData = traceFunc; 
h.onError = traceFunc;
```

This has yet to come back with an `onData` response (or `onError` for that matter). I know I have to be missing something simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to actually invoke the request?

```
h.request(false);
```

(using `false` for the `post` argument to make sure it's a `GET` instead of a `POST` request)